# Expecting multiple void methods with EasyMock 3.5

Tags: java, unit-testing, easymock

I am having an issue with Easymock, where I am trying to make a mock expecting a number of void calls. But I am having a problem making the mock fail when it should.

So I am expecting a call to persistConfiguration(Map) which i am absolutely sure is not being called. BUT the test passes all the same.

My mocked interface looks like this:

```
public abstract class MyMockedClass{
     public abstract void start() throws Exception;
     public abstract void stop() throws Exception;
     public abstract void persistConfiguration(Map<String, Object> newConfiguration) throws Exception;
}
```

The test looks like this

```
@RunWith(EasyMockRunner.class)
public class MyFailingTest{
@Mock
private MyMockedClass provider;
....
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception{
         Map<String, Object> expectedSetConfig = new HashMap<>();
         expectedSetConfig.put("String", setString);
         expectedSetConfig.put("File", testFile2.getCanonicalPath());

         /*Expect*/provider.start();
         expectLastCall().atLeastOnce();
         /*Expect*/provider.persistConfiguration(expectedSetConfig);
         expectLastCall().times(1);
         /*Expect*/provider.stop();
         expectLastCall().atLeastOnce();

         replay(provider);
    }

}
```

If I remove the expectation `provider.start()` and the matching `getLastCall` call the test fails with the message

> Unexpected method call MyMockedClass.start():
>       MyMockedClass.persistConfiguration({String=newString, File=C:\workspace\meh\stuff}): expected: 1, actual: 0
>       MyMockedClass.stop(): expected: at least 1, actual: 0

So the test CAN fail, but my question is: How do i make the test fail if either the `start`, `stop` or `persistConfiguration` method is called?
And the persistConfiguration method fail if it is called with anything but a map containing those specific values.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

I forgot to call `verify(provider)` after the test.

Setting

```
/*Expect*/provider.start();
expectLastCall().atLeastOnce();
```

only tells the mock to expect that call. It doesn't actually check the `.atLeastOnce()` part unless you call `verify`